# How do I apply flexbox to a gallery of images using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, sass

Using the code below, when I resize the viewport, the images stack on top of one another instead of shifting down one row. I'm pretty sure this is a bootstrap default, but I'm not sure how to change it. I've tried using the `d-flex` and `d-inline-flex` properties but I'm pretty lost.

HTML:

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-1.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-2.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-3.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-4.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-5.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-6.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-7.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-8.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="Mountain-Pictures/Mountain-gallery-9.png" class="gal-img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gal-img{
    width:300px;
    margin:50px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

Comment: don't use col-4 or col, it is strict in all screen... use col-sm-4 or col-md-4 for flexible view...

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap, you need to specify the size to make it responsive. At the moment, you have only put `col-4`, which means that the column will take up one-third of the available space of the container. This number is out of 12, so if you want it to take up half, you would say `col-6`, for example.

Because you have only put `col-4`, this will mean that each photo takes up one-third on any device from extra-small devices and up. If you want them to stop overlapping each other, you need to tell Bootstrap. You can do this by changing the ratio for different sizes. For example, try `col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10` so that each photo takes up one-third on large screens, half on medium screens and ten-twelfths on small screens.

I have changed it in my CodePen here: https://codepen.io/St3ph3n92/pen/ZEbyOOj

```css
.gal-img{
    width:300px;
    margin:50px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559321966-04643588828f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" class="gal-img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to read more about this, you could check the Bootstrap documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Also, here is another useful tool I have used that might come in handy if you're using Bootstrap: https://layoutit.com/build

I hope this helps!